# Regarding SIgnals in C

Tags: c, ubuntu, signals, mdns

I understand with the help of Signals, we can pass interrupts to the executing C programs, and direct them to behave according to the Handlers assigned. When ctrl+c is pressed, SIGINT is executed.

Currently I am running a setup, where in  I have 2 systems. Both have servers(DiscoveryServers) capable of multicast extension(mDNS). I have made use of Signals like SIGHUP and SIGKILL.
I am trying to understand what SIGKILL and SIGHUP actually does here.
So in one of the systems, I have an extra server which registers to the local discovery server. This server is advertised throughout the network with the help of mDNS.

Now, through SIGHUP, i can see that the terminal close of the server is detected amd the corresponding handler is executed.
But when I shut the system down, both the server and the Discovery server of that system, should go off. But that is detected inconsistently( not always) through SIGHUP. I tried with SIGKILL and still the response is the same. It is very unclear as to why it is happening?

Is it because the mDNS is using UDP and the UDP is unreliable?

Eg: Consider A and B as two systemss. Both A and B have discoveryservers running (capable of mDNS: meaning they can advertise the server records throughout the network) which contains the list of servers running on their system respectively. An extra server (server E) running on A, registers to discovery server of A. Now  the registered server records are also advertised. Because of mDNS, the discovery server in B also updates its cache with all the advertiesments from system A. B can be seen as a client, runs a particular API, to get the list of servers running on the netowrk.  All of this works fine.

If i close the terminal of the extra server on purpose, SIGHUP handler works smoothly. I can see from logs of both the discovery servers that the extra server has been removed.

Now if i shutdown the system A unexpectedly, the terminals running the server applications should close. That can be achieved with SIGHUP handler. What i observe from the log of system B is that, sometimes there are clean removal of the servers, sometimes partial.

There is no clarity as to why it is happening.

Comment: If you shut the system down, the processes are killed anyway. Am I missing something?

Comment: Don't use SIGKILL unless you intend the process to die.  You can't catch SIGKILL.

Comment: @Zoso: I have updated the question with the example scenario

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  When you mention "can't catch SIGKILL", does it mean that the corresponding handler is not executed? What is meant by "can't catch"? Sorry just a beginner

Comment: Yes.  You can't usefully set a function to respond to SIGKILL.  The process to which you send SIGKILL dies unconditionally, assuming that the process sending the signal has appropriate permission.

Comment: @RakshanPremsagarKapikad Read [this](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) on `signal`. It's a very good intro on the topic. Also, it has this `The signals SIGKILL and SIGSTOP cannot be caught, blocked, or
       ignored.`

Comment: @RakshanPremsagarKapikad Also, the basic problem of yours boils down to whether a message sent from a signal handler that's running on a system being shut down can actually be sent.

Comment: @RakshanPremsagarKapikad You might need to give the system some time to actually send the UDP packet. Transmission always takes time, and passing a message through all the layers adds to it.